# Change directory in docker alpine failing

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, alpine-linux

Trying to build a dockerfile with alpine image and install set of directories. Here is the script below. It works fine until mkdir but does not change to /opt to download the git code.

The git code gets downloaded only to /src. Not sure whey the cd /opt command does not work.

```
FROM alpine
ADD . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN apk update
RUN apk add git
RUN mkdir /opt
RUN cd /opt  && git clone --recursive https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python.git 
RUN ls -al 
RUN cd azure-iot-sdk-python && ls -al build_all/linux
```

Comment: Why not just `WORKDIR` again?

Comment: I can do that but would like to know why the above commands do not work..If its ubuntu its working fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *current working directory* is reset for every `RUN` to the value of the last `WORKDIR`.

So, because of that, this line `RUN cd azure-iot-sdk-python && ls -al build_all/linux` is doing it from here `/src`, and your cloned repo is in `opt`.

So both of this will work:

```
RUN cd /opt/azure-iot-sdk-python && ls -al build_all/linux
```

and:

```
WORKDIR /opt
RUN cd azure-iot-sdk-python && ls -al build_all/linux
```

Answer (score 1):

Robert is right, and you could avoid this problem by following the Dockerfile best practice, and have only one RUN, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/